# one parent sys_refcursor record contains a child sys_refcursor type with multiple records

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

DB: Oracle 11gR2

Hello,

I have 2 tables with parent child relationship (one-to-many) between them. Now I need to return a ref-cursor from a stored procedure which will return one row from the parent table corresponding to the input parameter and the corresponding records (can be an array) from the child tables. Note we don't want to repeat the result set from the parent. So basically we just want to return one record where the detail column is an array of records or a child sys refcursor inside the parent sys recursor. Question is how can I do it?

Below is the sample tables, data and usual procedure (returns multiple rows -- which is not intended):

```
create table parent 
(
    class_id        varchar2(2),
    class_name      varchar2(10),
    subject_name    varchar2(10),
    constraint pk_id primary key (class_id)
);

create table child
(
    class_id      varchar2(10),
    student_name    varchar2(10),
    result          varchar2(10),
    constraint fk_id Foreign key (class_id) references parent(class_id)
);

insert into parent values('1', 'class_1', 'subject_1');
insert into parent values('2', 'class_2', 'subject_2');
insert into parent values('3', 'class_3', 'subject_3');
insert into parent values('4', 'class_4', 'subject_4');

insert into child values ('1', 'student_1', 'pass');
insert into child values ('1', 'student_2', 'fail');
insert into child values ('1', 'student_3', 'pass');
insert into child values ('2', 'student_1', 'pass');
insert into child values ('2', 'student_4', 'fail');

create or replace PROCEDURE get_data (
    class_id_in        IN      parent.class_id%TYPE,
    student_list_cur   OUT     SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN student_list_cur FOR
    SELECT p.class_name,
           p.subject_name,
           c.student_name,
           c.result
    FROM parent p, child c
    WHERE p.class_id = c.class_id
    AND p.class_id = class_id_in;

END get_data;
```

Again note that the sys-refcursor returns:

```
class_name     subject_name     student_name     result
-------------------------------------------------------
class_1         subject_1       student_1        pass
class_1         subject_1       student_2        fail
class_1         subject_1       student_3        pass
```

Rather what I want is one record like:

```
parent.class_name,
parent.subject_name,
child.array_of_records SYS_REFCURSOR
```

Where child.array_of_records contains multiple of records of child.student_name, child.result corresponding to the same class_id.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `CURSOR SUBQUERY`?

```
OPEN student_list_cur FOR
SELECT p.class_name,
       p.subject_name,
       CURSOR(SELECT c.student_name,
                     c.result
              FROM
                 child c
              WHERE p.class_id = c.class_id)
FROM parent p
WHERE p.class_id = class_id_in;
```

Comment: Thanks Masheswaran, it works. However one concern of this approach (I was told) is that for one parent it can open multiple child cursors, hence can cause some issue. I was wondering if an nested-table/array can be used to pass the child records inside the parent sys_refcursor. Can you please shed some light on it.